# How to compare two csv files using Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, robotframework

I would like to compare difference between two csv files using robot framework .Test case should fail if there is difference and pass if there is no difference.I have tried DiffLibrary in Robot framework but is returning pass status when records are not sorted. Can someone guide me how this can be achieved or if there is any alternative way to do this.

My first.csv file is having data like below

```
Benchmark Name,Policy Name,No of Rules,Policy Measurement SLO,Policy Remediation SLO,No of Rules Compliant in MSLO,No of Rules Non-Compliant in RSLO,No of Rules Non-Compliant OUT RSLO
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Benchmark v1.0.0,PCI,281,1 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,130
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark v1.2.0,PCI,281,5 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,137
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark v1.5.0,PCI,281,1 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,135
```

And my second.csv file is having data like below

```
Benchmark Name,Policy Name,No of Rules,Policy Measurement SLO,Policy Remediation SLO,No of Rules Compliant in MSLO,No of Rules Non-Compliant in RSLO,No of Rules Non-Compliant OUT RSLO
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark v1.2.0,PCI,281,5 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,137
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Benchmark v1.0.0,PCI,281,1 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,130
CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark v1.5.0,PCI,281,1 MONTHS,1 MONTHS,150,135
```

Robot code is below

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DiffLibrary
Library  OperatingSystem


*** Test Cases ***


Diffing two files one being different
    Run Keyword And Expect Error  differences*  Diff Files  first.csv  second.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer worked for me ,even if data is sorted .It will give the result as pass if there is no mismatch and fail if data mismatches.

csv_difference.py

```
import sys
     def csv_diff(file_f,file_g):
        #file_f = sys.argv[1]
        #file_g = sys.argv[2]
        set_f = set()
        set_g = set()
        with open(file_f) as f:
            line = f.readline().strip()
            while line:
                set_f.add(line)
                line = f.readline().strip()
        with open(file_g) as g:
            line = g.readline().strip()
            while line:
                set_g.add(line)
                line = g.readline().strip()
        diff = set_f - set_g

        # print set_f
        # print set_g
        # print diff
        if diff:
            #print "Data mismatch between the files"
            return False
        else:
            #print " Data Matches "
            return True
```

csv-difference.robot

```
*** Settings ***
    Library     OperatingSystem
    Library      csv_difference.py


    *** Test Cases ***
    CSV file comparison 
         ${output}=   Run keyword  csv diff   first.csv   second.csv
        Should Be True  '${output}' == 'True'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just using BuiltIn's Should Be Equal As Strings?

```
# Using Get File you easily get a file's content into a string variable
${csvA} =    Get File    ${filePathA}
${csvB} =    Get File    ${filePathB}
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${csvA}    ${csvB}
```

I use that model for comparing lines only, you might need to edit the file string in case there's difference in file encoding (BOM leaves a special BOM character in the beginning of the file, etc.)

Comment: Hi Lubos, Thanks for your response. Will it give same result even if rows are not sorted ?

Comment: No, because the entire file would be considered a single string and any changes in line order would make it unequal.

Comment: If you do not care about lines order just do following:

    ${csvA} =    Get File    ${filePathA}
    ${csvA} =    Split To Lines    ${csvA}
    ${csvB} =    Get File    ${filePathB}
    ${csvB} =    Split To Lines    ${csvB}
    Sort List    ${csvA}
    Sort List    ${csvB}
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${csvA}    ${csvB}

Answer (score 0):

```
def csv_diff(file_f,file_g):
    with open(file_f) as f:
        textf = f.readlines()
        textf.pop(1)
        set_f = set(textf)
    with open(file_g) as g:
        textg = g.readlines()
        textg.pop(1)
        set_g = set(textg)
    if set_f == set_g:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

basicly, I transfer csv to dict and use jsondeepcompare library to compare csv. thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32780325)